# Create label for Checkbox inside element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, checkbox

I try to make lines dynamically, the problem is when I add a checkbox with label  dynamically using javascript does not work. However the one I created with Html by default works correctly.

In fact I want the image that I added (on.png / off.png) replaces the checkbox. When I do it only with html (checkbox + label) the code works, but now I only want to create the element with Javascript, I can chow the label but it when I click It's not work.

This is all my code :

Main.html

```
 <HTML>
 <HEAD>
<TITLE>  </TITLE>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
    function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "checkbox";
        element1.id =  "id2" ;
        cell1.appendChild(element1);

        // Create label
        var label = document.createElement("label");
        label.for =  "id2" ;
        cell1.appendChild(label);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "text";
        cell3.appendChild(element2);


    }

    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }

        }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }

</SCRIPT>
 </HEAD>
<BODY>
<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

<INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

<TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
    <TR>
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"  id="id1" /> <label for="id1" > </label>   </TD>
        <TD> 1 </TD>
        <TD> <INPUT type="text" /> </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

style.css

```
 input[type=checkbox] {
  display:none;
}

 input[type=checkbox] + label
 {
   background: url(images/off.png) no-repeat;
   height: 64px;
   width: 64px;
   display:inline-block;
   padding: 0 0 0 0px;
 }

  input[type=checkbox]:checked + label
 {
    background: url(images/on.png) no-repeat;
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  }
```

Help me please.

Comment: You should really look into using a templating library like [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js). It'll make your development easier and the project will be more extensible, maintainable, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change this

```
label.for =  "id2" ;
```

to this

```
label.htmlFor =  "id2" ;
```

Because some JavaScript implementations didn't allow keywords/reserved words as object properties, a workaround had to be made for the `for` property, so they chose `htmlFor`.

A similar situation was with `.class`, which is why they use `.className`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is line 17, `label.for =  "id2" ;` that should be `label.htmlFor = "id2";`